# Translation does not show non-ASCII characters correctly

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have a SAPUI5 application.

The translated text is shown incorrectly in a dialog, while the translation is shown correct in the launchpad. Please see the following picture:

[image]

While the translation file is loaded for German language, it does not show [ÖÄÜß] correctly in the dialog. However it does show *ö* correctly in the launchpad page.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `/resources/configuration/propertiesFileSourceEncoding` to `UTF-8` in the tooling configuration file (typically `ui5.yaml`).

1. In `ui5.yaml`:

   ```
   resources:
     configuration:
       propertiesFileSourceEncoding: UTF-8
   ```
2. And in `package.json`:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "@ui5/cli": "<at least 1.7.0>",
     ...
   },
   ```
3. Re-build and deploy the app again.

---

### About `propertiesFileSourceEncoding`

> This option specifies the source encoding of `*.properties` files of the project. Those files will be read in the given encoding and any non-ASCII characters replaced with the respective unicode escape sequences. [(doc)](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/Configuration/#resources-optional)

Comment: The setting is like this already. In the WEB IDE it shows all the string correct but when I deploy it, it shows the string in dialogs wrong. I changed the UTF-8 characters in my i18n files like this: `addressInfo=Oskar-J\u00E4ger-Stra\u00DFe 170, 50825 Cologne, Germany` and it solved my problem.

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari That is exactly what `propertiesFileSourceEncoding` is supposed to do: replacing non-ASCII chars like `öäüß` to encoded unicode-number (e.g. `\u00F6`) before building & deployment. Otherwise, app developers would have to replace all the non-ASCII chars one by one by themselves. I guess the reason why it didn't have any effect in your case was probably the lower `@ui5/cli` version as `propertiesFileSourceEncoding` is supported only as of `1.7.0`?