# How do I display special character in Fiori UI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to display special characters like Circumflex (&Ecirc) or Acute (&‌Vacute) in UI5 Fiori. I am not using index.html but I am using component.js. All the answers to this question insert 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>`
into index.html but I don't have index.html. So how will I do it with component.js?

I have tried using uriencode but that didn't work.

For example I have card control and I want to escape the text in the card header.
Here is the code:

```
<f:Card>
    <f:header>
        <card:Header id="header" title="value"/>
    </f:header>
```

I am trying to escape the title for card with header id.

Comment: For other readers: in case of using an `i18n` model with special characters in the `*.properties` file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834203/translation-does-not-show-non-ascii-characters-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mhm.. you can use it anywhere.. so you just have to add the html code for the character you can look for example here: https://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

you put the character code where you want it to have